# Is there a way to set an uploaded file size limit in tornado?

Tags: http, file-upload, limit, tornado, filesize

I am using [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) to make an image processing RESTful service, which is accepting images uploaded by general HTTP means like `multipart/form-data`. I then access them in handlers using `self.request.files`.

It could be that an adversary will try to upload a huge file to break down a service. Is there any way to tell tornado an uploaded file size limit, exceeding which file should be discarded and error HTTP status should be set?

Answer (score 11):

I've tried this, It works! `max_buffer_size` default value is 100 M.

```
import tornado.httpserver

app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/upload/', UploadFileHandler),
])

server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, max_buffer_size=10485760000)  # 10G
server.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a max_buffer_size parameter when creating the server. For example to allow for 160MB uploads"

```
HTTPServer(app, max_buffer_size=167772160)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure this on the web server. For example, using nginx:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Edit: The stream that HttpServer uses has a max_buffer_size property. HttpServer will not accept uploads bigger than this. The default value for it is 100MB. It seems to me that HttpServer simply closes the connection instead of sending a HTTP response when this limit is reached.

Comment: So the question is how to configure this option for **tornado**.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question to contain slightly more useful information.